# Undefined reference to 'specificFunction'

Tags: c, header-files, referenceerror

So I know about .h and .c files, but I'm having a problem getting my code to compile.  I'm missing something!  The Main.c includes "Converter.h", which has

```
  #ifndef CONVERTER_H
  #define   CONVERTER_H

  void runConverter(char *);

  #endif
```

and my converter.c file has the implementation..

```
#include "Converter.h"
#include "Stack.h"
#include "Queue.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int checkChar(char input);
void printQueue(QueueP que);
void runConverter(char *input){ .... code etc (calls a stack and a queue 
and does stuff)}
```

The problem is, I'm getting undefined reference in each of my files.  The .c isn't finding the info in Stack.h or Queue.h and the converterTester isn't finding my main runConverter function. Kind of confused, but I think its something small.  Any help?

Comment: You should post your `Converter.h`, `Stack.h` and `Queue.h`. The information you have provided is insufficient to find out what might be wrong.

Comment: are you building this into a library and then linking to a binary?

Comment: Could you show us what you use to build? Is it `gcc *.c` or a Makefile or something else??

Comment: I commented down below, but will restate here.  I was using code-blocks IDE, but having trouble with the program structure.  Admittedly I am new to linking multiple files (I'm used to using only one header file).  So I followed the advice below and just opened a linux VM and did the gcc command line route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the other files, and with no idea how you build the executable, pure guesswork...

You need to compile each of the sources, *and link all the objects together*:

```
gcc -g -O2 -Wall -c Converter.c
gcc -g -O2 -Wall -c Stack.c
gcc -g -O2 -Wall -c Queue.c
gcc -g -o pgm Converter.o Stack.o Queue.o
```

The `-c` (compile only) flags in the first three lines are crucial, you don't want the compiler to try to create an executable in one go. And no, the compiler has no idea what other pieces you want to include in the executable gotten from `Converter.c`. Here on [SO] we are pretty good at guessing, but guessing is for humans, not compilers.

Comment: Cool, yeah that did the trick.  I was using an IDE (which uses gcc [code::blocks]), but having trouble creating the project structure.  Linux -> gcc command line like you typed up worked like a charm.  Thanks.